# Different margins for different page styles in memoir

Tags: margins, memoir, letters

I am trying to produce a document in `memoir` with a letterhead on the first page only. I have created a custom `pagestyle` for the letterhead with a larger upper margin to include the header; but this larger margin is preserved even when I revert to the `plain` pagestyle without a header. How can I change the upper margin only in one `pagestyle`?

```
%page style with different margins in memoir
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\settypeblocksize{9in}{6.5in}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\setheadfoot{5em}{2em}
\newlength{\marginPlusHead}
\setlength{\marginPlusHead}{1in}
\addtolength{\marginPlusHead}{\headsep}
\setulmarginsandblock{\marginPlusHead}{1in}{*}

\copypagestyle{letterhead}{plain}
\makeoddhead{letterhead}{}{{\Huge LETTERHEAD}}{}
\makeheadrule{letterhead}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\thispagestyle{letterhead}
\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The margin isn't part of the style.  (Commenting out \thispagestyle... looks the same as the second page.)  Try using the geometry package to create a one page margin change.  Or just use \raisebox for the header (it's only one page).

Comment: My question is, can I include the margin settings in the page style?

Comment: @AndrewCashner, no, use other methods for the front page. In my university letter class I used the letter starting macros/environments to move the text on the first page down compared to the later pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to create a fake header using \raisebox.  If you set \AddMargin to 0pt the text on pages 1 and 2 will be aligned.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\settypeblocksize{9in}{6.5in}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\setheadfoot{5em}{2em}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\AddMargin}% additional margin for this page
\setlength{\AddMargin}{1in}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
% places the rule \headsep above text area
\noindent\raisebox{\headsep}[\AddMargin][0pt]%
{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfil{\Huge HEADER}\newline%
\rule{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}}%
\hspace{-\textwidth}}% takes up no space
\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm accepting the answer as a demonstration of one way to put a header on the first page. This solves the immediate problem of creating a letterhead, but does not answer the question of how to include a margin adjustment in a `memoir` pagestyle. The other possibility, as noted in the comments, is to use `geometry`, but since `memoir` provides its own layout interface it seems dangerous to combine the two.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use memoir class.  You can read the manual as well as I can.

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize you. I don't think the manual explains how to do this. The point of my comment was supposed to be to thank you for the solution to the letterhead problem, and to point out to other users that apparently it is not possible to do what I was asking in the original question.

Comment: No problem.  I really didn't expect this to be accepted, since it was just a demonstrration.