# Defining new geometry (running arbitrary code) in memoir page styles

Tags: header-footer, margins, memoir, fancyhdr, geometry

Is it even possible? `memoir`'s own documentation about page styles seems to only touch upon the use of different headers and footers and doesn't appear to support adding margin information. Since memoir nevertheless does plenty of same things as `fancyhdr` and I've seen worries about incompatibilities, I'm looking towards working `memoir`-only.

Using `fancyhdr` one can define a page style with pretty much arbitrary commands because all the page style settings are just a bunch of different commands in an open field and I can plug in a `\newgeometry` command in there to adjust the margins to my liking for that style:

```
\fancypagestyle{koe}{
\newgeometry{margin=1.8cm}
\fancyhf{} 
\setlength\headheight{30pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo.pdf}}
\fancyhead[R]{\sffamily\thepage}
}
```

I also need to minimize the commands necessary since I'm working on templates for coworkers, so using a custom margin definition in beginning of every new document is out of question; **this margin (and maybe finally even font) information needs to be included in `\pagestyle{}`** so all people need to do is `\input` our own style file with the necessary commands and packages, and then simply choose a pre-defined style with `\pagestyle{}` — two lines of simple code and they're all ready to go working on the actual content already laid out in the correct style.

A new document should therefore begin like this:

```
\input{../ourstyle.sty} %this file contains documentclass, all packages and custom commands
\pagestyle{styleforthiscategoryofdocuments} %this should define headers, footers and margins (maybe even the fontstyle in my wildest dreams)
\begin{document}
%actual content
```

This old thread touched on the topic but never resolved, instead turning to a workaround: [Different margins for different page styles in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199125/different-margins-for-different-page-styles-in-memoir)

EDIT: Suggestion by alephzero sounded great but this posed another problem. If I define, for example:

```
\newcommand{\mystyle}[1]{
\clearpage\newgeometry{margin=1.5cm}
\pagestyle{#1}
}
```

... it still doesn't pair a given page style with pre-defined margins. One way would be to create a totally new command for every style/margin combo, but that's again making things more complicated. Instead of having, say `\report`, `\exercises`, `\instructions`, it would be better to have a single command (`\mystyle`) with one argument. If there is no easier way, I suppose I'll just make a big if-else tree to match the margins with page styles. :/

Comment: you can only change the text width (and so margin) at forced page breaks so changing the geometry in a page style can never really be supported (in fancyhdr or memoir versions)

Comment: you should not normally `\input` such code but  include it via `\usepackage` or here it sounds like you want to set up the initial page layout so better input it via `\documentclass`

Comment: The files to be inputted already have necessary packages set up with `\usepackage` and also has the memoir `\documentclass` set up. However, while all the file we're going to produce will use same packages and gladly use memoir class, they are going to need different margins. `\newgeometry` seems to be by far the most meaningfull command to change margins and I was looking for a way to automatically call this with a page style. If `memoir` has another way to incorporate margins to page styles, that'll work as well.

Comment: geometry conceptually has to be set before the text is set (as it specifies the width to use for line breaking) whereas a page style specifies head and foot applied to the page after page breaking (so long after line breaking) so logically these are quite distinct although at a forced page break they do more or less accidentally coincide. However it would be better to use commands like `\mainmatter` (or the start of the document)  as points to set the geometry rather than rely on a page style only being set in a "safe" place.

Comment: If the files to be input have the needed  `\usepackage` it is better to give them a .sty extension than a .tex one and input them using \usepackage

Comment: I updated the original post to include an example of an expected preamble. I'll check out the `\mainmatter`feature; I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Why can't you define a command like `\newcommand\mypagestyle{\clearpage\newgeometry{...}\pagestyle{whatever-it's-called}}` and then get your users to do `\mypagestyle`?

Comment: Well, heck. You're right, that wrapping actually does solve the problem. :D (Not an answer to if memoir can support custom code with page style declaration, which I'd still like to know, but that does fit my needs.)

Cheers!

Comment: @alephzero Actually, my joy was exaggerated; I can easily define a new command that encompasses the margin setting with pagestyle setting, but the pagestyle setting still has a variable defined elsewhere. If I define a command, I'll have to put specific margin data there, but the new command won't know beforehand which page style will be used. :/

Comment: oh you already have .sty extension so `\input{../ourstyle.sty} ` can be `\usepackage{../ourstyle}` or better `\usepackage{ourstyle} ` with no change to `ourstyle.tex`  which would also allow your preambles to be simplified further removing the pagestyle/geometry setting entirely as `\usepackage[thiscategoryofdocuments]{ourstyle}` is all you need in the preamble and the package code for that option can set the geometry and page style.

Comment: Normally margins are kept constant throughout a document. In your case if a user has several different pagestyles in a document do you want to have different margins and not a uniform layout throughout the document? I have a vague memory that if you switch between `\onecolumn` then `\twocolumn` and back to `\onecolumn` then LaTeX recalculates the page layout between these. But as David said you can really only change the textwidth at paragraph/pagebreaks.

Comment: Making your code into a class will probably make some editors behave better with users' documents. I don't know if this is a concern or not, but some editors need the `\documentclass` in order to treat the content as LaTeX code. You can still have options, obviously, so `\documentclass[thiscategoryofdocument]{ourstyle}` would work.

Comment: If you don't want the geometry or header/footers stuff from Memoir, it might be easier not to use Memoir in the first place. A standard `report` or `book` might work better. Memoir does some nice stuff, but if you're going to screw that stuff up and fling it in the bin anyway, you might just as well not invite it to dine in the first place (to mix metaphors horribly).